# Xamarin.Android app: brute forcing netstandard?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, .net-core, .net-standard

Have a custom .NET core library on myget.org which targets distinctly:

- netstandard1.6
- monoandroid60

For various technical reasons I'd like to keep the monoandroid60 target around; that said, I've got an android app which I'd specifically like it to use the netstandard1.6 flavor.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You should be able to use `netstandard1.6` with Xamarin.Android 7.0+. https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md However you might run into an issue as described in this video by Immo - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNUUAIGHupc

I would honestly recommend waiting for `netstandard2.0` as it will be the big release for supporting this out of the box.

Comment: The trouble is, Xamarin Android doesn't use the netstandard1.6 target - even though it can.  It always favors the monoandroid60 target, if present.

Comment: netstandard1.6 doesn't really give you enough to be useful with as pointed out in the video I linked. Thus waiting for 2.0 or using < 1.6 should work.

Comment: That might be workable, my lib supports 1.3 also.  So the question adjusts to, how do we force Xamarin to target 1.3 over monoandroid6.0?